# Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: javascript, preact

I'm building a widget that was getting messed up because of the parent website's style component. Currently, I'm pushing everything to the shadow root like this. Without it, the style of the widget changes.

However, I'm encountering a new error. How can I fix it and add styles to the shadow root at the same time?

```
import { h, render } from 'preact';
import { App } from './App';
import loader from './loader';
import { Configurations } from './models';
import style from "./layout/main.css";

/**
 * Default configurations that are overridden by
 * parameters in embedded script.
 */
const defaultConfig: Configurations = {
    debug: false,
    serviceBaseUrl: '',
    // minimized: false,
    disableDarkMode: true,
    text: {},
    styles: {},
};





// main entry point - calls loader and render Preact app into supplied element
loader(window, defaultConfig, window.document.currentScript, (el, config) =>
{
    const shadowHost = document.querySelector('#widget-_hw');
    shadowHost?.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const shadowRoot = document.querySelector('#widget-_hw')?.shadowRoot
    const renderIn = document.createElement('div');
    const styleTag = document.createElement('style');
    styleTag.innerHTML = style;
    shadowRoot?.appendChild(styleTag); 
    renderIn.setAttribute('id', 'render-div');
    shadowRoot?.appendChild(renderIn);
    render(h(App, { ...config, element: el }), renderIn)
}
);
```